# Check if two files match in 2 column values and print those lines to a new output file

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to match two files based on two column values per file. If both of the values of "BP" and "P" match in the same line, I want to print those lines on a third file, which is like file 2.

File 1:

```
CHR BP BETA SE P PHENOTYPE FDR CATEGORY SNP
10 110408937 3.386e+00 1.333e+00 1.112e-02 1 1 Medication rs113627704
10 110408937 4.409e+00 1.623e+00 6.602e-03 2 1 Cardiovascular rs113627704
10 110408937 2.382e+00 1.124e+00 3.414e-02 3 1 Medication rs113627704
```

File 2:

```
CHR F SNP BP P TOTAL
10 1 rs113627704 110408937 1.112e-02 456
4 1 rs43567 2345677 0.045457 567
3 1 rs567899 479899 0.3456 223
```

Desired output:

```
CHR BP BETA SE P PHENOTYPE FDR CATEGORY SNP
10 110408937 3.386e+00 1.333e+00 1.112e-02 1 1 Medication rs113627704
```

I have tried the following two:

```
​awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$5]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$2,$5]){print b}}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Here I get the error "bash: awk: command not found." I use awk all the time and it always works.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$4,$5]=$0; next} ($4,$5) in a {print a[$2,$5], $0}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Here I get an empty file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4,$5]=$0;next}(($2,$5) in a)' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
CHR BP BETA SE P PHENOTYPE FDR CATEGORY SNP
10 110408937 3.386e+00 1.333e+00 1.112e-02 1 1 Medication rs113627704
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {         # process file2 as output we want are from file1
    a[$4,$5]=$0   # desired fields are 4th and 5th, use them as hash key
    next          # move to next record
}                 # process file1 below this point
(($2,$5) in a)    # test if 2nd and 5th in hash and output
' file2 file1     # mind the file order
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some invisible character(s) in the word `awk` in your command:

```
​awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$5]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$2,$5]){print b}}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Using the string from your command:

```
$ type awk
-bash: type: awk: not found
```

Manually typing `awk`:

```
$ type awk
awk is hashed (/usr/bin/awk)
```